# HLSL Unity5> Multiple render targets

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, vertex-shader

I am attempting to specify a frag output into a set texture (render target) depending on some logic.

**To summarise my shader:**
I am preforming a Texture3D raycasting method that allows for the user to 'see' inside the texture 3D data.

My issue arises when wanting to sample an area of this main texture and dump it into another of a smaller resolution (allowing for an eventual 'zooming' affect)

My research thus far has brought me to the use of Multiple render targets . in that (to my understanding) I would send this frag function output to another function which then outputs to set different targets.

Feedback appreciated;especially if there is an easier way to sample area into another texture (I have tried various compute shader methods- CPU methods are too slow) a CPU based analogy being the Unity's:
[GetPixels](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) function

**Extract:**

**.float alpha** is actually a raycast step result

**.float4 t** the colour plus alpha at mapping of the input Texture3D

**._sample** a pseudo bool flag for sampling

**.texture3Dsampler** (within commented if statement) is the smaller resolution Texture3D that I wish to write to; given the pixel being evaluated of the input Texture3D is within texture3Dsampler bounds from a certain start point - as shown in if statement logic.

```
        float a = (1 - alpha);
            float4 t = float4(t3d, a);

            //Cn = Current pixel
            int Cx = start.x;
            int Cy = start.y;
            int Cz = start.z;

            if(_sample == 1 && 
               ((Cx >= _XSS) && (Cx <= (_XSS+_Tex3DSampled.x))) &&
               ((Cy >= _YSS) && (Cy <= (_XSS+_Tex3DSampled.y))) &&
               ((Cz >= _ZSS) && (Cz <= (_YSS+_Tex3DSampled.z)))
              )
            {
                //render t into BOTH texture3D to screen output and texture3Dsampler output
            }
            else //if not sampling into other Texture3d, simple return to render t onto screen
            {
                return t; //returning into t
            }                               

        }
```

Comment: I would have expected that if you wanted a multi-resolution 3D texture that you would apply traditional filtering to the larger resolution texture to create a smaller resolution.  Is this something separate from your raycasting attempt, or are you literally trying to create the smaller resolution texture by raycasting?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
To confirm I'm trying to output a section of the texture to an input override. Following the casting methods.

So to but it a bit clearer here's the process.

.Raycast all pixels into projection works space.
.Send all pixels to main output texture 3D.
.then , for all pixels within certain dimensions from a given start point (determined in ray cast method) send pixels to overide secondary texture.